# How can I detect .NET 3.5 in WiX?

Tags: .net, wix, version

I'm trying to detect which version .NET is installed using WiX. I've tried:

```
<Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 3.5 or higher.'>
  <![CDATA[MsiNetAssemblySupport >= "3.5.0.0"]]>
</Condition>
```

But that won't work, because the MsiNetAssemblySupport property checks the version of `fusion.dll`, which wasn't updated from version 2.0 in .NET 3.0 or 3.5.

Is it feasible to check for the presence of the .NET libraries in the system directory? How would I do that using WiX? Or is there some way to do that using the registry?

(I realize that there's a WiX user email list, but this is the Oughts-- I don't like 1980s technology, I like stuff I can easily search.)

Comment: It is ironic that all the answers say search on Google. When this is the first hit on Google.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Visual Studio -> WiX project -> Add Reference -> WixNetFxExtension.dll and then:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK35" />
<Condition Message="This setup requires the .NET Framework 3.5 to be installed.">
  Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK35
</Condition>
```

[Full details](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_for_dotnet.htm), including all [.NET version properties](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm) available in the extension. Also consider whether condition message should be [localized](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/make_installer_localizable.html).

Comment: error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:NETFRAMEWORK35' in section 'Product:*'.

Comment: @mmr - I've clarified the answer, this is all I have to do to get it working. This will add reference to wixproj, which adds -ext WixNetFxExtension automatically to command line.

Comment: Anyone know if NETFRAMEWORK35 is true when only the .Net 4.0 framework is present?

Comment: @KevM, I added another link, `NETFRAMEWORK35 Set to #1 if the .NET Framework 3.5 is installed (not set otherwise).` Of course you'll have to test this for yourself, but the documentation suggests no, it wouldn't be true.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be no. You cannot (in a reliable way) check whether .NET framework version X or higher is installed. You can only check whether a specific .NET version is installed.
Now that .NET 4.0 is released it is annoying that you have to install .NET 3.5 even if .NET 4.0 is already installed.

I hope the WiX developers will find a solution to this problem.