# MSI .NET Framework Prerequisite

Tags: windows-8, windows-installer, prerequisites

I have an MSI file with .NET Framework 2.0 Prerequisite. In windows 8 .NEt framework 2.0 is not installed by default and when i run the .msi, it says you need to install .NET framework 2.0.

But Windows 8 already comes with .NET framework 4.0 or 4.5 which supports older versions and indeed would be able to run the msi file if i could say this msi file can also run on .NET framework 4.0. How can i do that?

More precisely, how can i configure an msi file to have a prerequisite such that min .net framework version 2.0 but can run on newer versions?

I can do this for assemblies adding the configuration below.

```
<configuration> 
  <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
   <supportedRuntime version="v3.0" />
   <supportedRuntime version="v3.5" />
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO question [How can I detect .net 3.5 in WiX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682805/how-can-i-detect-net-3-5-in-wix) appears to answer this. It also points to [another post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/07/07/8705318.aspx) that discusses this when not using WiX

Answer (score 0):

If you install the .Net framework 3.5, that will provide 2.0 as well.  Only 4.5 is installed by default.  Go to the Windows features and turn on .Net framework 3.5.