# How can I detect whether .NET Framework 3.5 or higher is installed in WiX?

Tags: wix, .net-framework-version

I currently using the following markup in my WiX installer project to check if .NET Framework 3.5 or greater is installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect .NET 3.5 in WiX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682805/how-can-i-detect-net-3-5-in-wix)

Answer (score 0):

there is no Release Reg_DWORD for .Net Framework 3.5 But you can detect it using the following RegistrySearch:

```
<Property Id="NET35INSTALLED" Secure="yes" Admin="yes"/>
<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="Net35Installed"
  Variable="NET35INSTALLED"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5"
  Value="Install"
  Win64="no"
  Format="compatible"
/>
```

To use it in a condition use NET35INSTALLED = 1.

See more information in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#detect-net-framework-10-through-40).

Answer (score -1):

Visit :
https://www.mking.net/blog/detecting-dotnet-framework-versions-with-wix

there you see the check for 4.7.2 installed :

```
<PropertyRef Id='WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED'/>
<Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 4.7.2 (or greater) to be installed.'>
        <![CDATA[Installed OR (WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED >= "#461808")]]>
</Condition>
```

You only need to replace the release key with the 3.5 version..

Comment: I was not able to find the release key for dot net 3.5 version. Will you be able to help here @harm-van-der-haas?